# Changing the column name based on a partial string or substring

Tags: r, regex, string, substring, rename

I have a data frame `df`. I can generate this data frame 5 times for 5 different variables. Let's say variables names are:

```
Apple  # apple_df
Mango  # mango_df
Banana # banana_df
Potato # potato_df
Tomato # tomato_df
```

Each time the data frame is generated one of the column names is quite large such as:

```
Apple - Growth Level Judgement    # Column name for apple_df
Mango - Growth Level Judgement    # Column name for mango_df
Banana - Growth Level Judgement   # Column name for banana_df
Potato - Growth Level Judgement   # Column name for potato_df
Tomato - Growth Level Judgement   # Column name for tomato_df
```

I want to change the above column names to just the word `Growth` across each of the files.

Is there a way to do it effectively across all data frames by using one common line of code (separately)?

I can use the complete name in each of the files separately but was wondering if we could have a generalised solution:

```
# For Apple data frame

# Update column name
setnames(apple_df, 
         old = c('Apple - Growth Level Judgement'), 
         new = c('Growth'))
```

If I use the following regex-based solution, it only replaces the part of the string name that is common across all data frames. Unfortunately, not the whole name.

```
gsub(x = names(apple_df), 
     pattern = "Growth Level Judgement$", replacement = "Growth")
```

##### Related posts:

The following post is related but it strips the known part of the string [Remove part of column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176287/remove-part-of-column-name). In my case, I want to detect the occurrence of a column based on a partial string that stays the same across multiple datasets. But once the string is detected in the column name, I want to change the whole column name. The following posts may also be related but do not meet my needs
[r Remove parts of column name after certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800704/r-remove-parts-of-column-name-after-certain-characters) or [Rename column names according to pattern matching R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527429/rename-column-names-according-to-pattern-matching-r)

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list and use `lapply`/`map` to change name of every dataframe. `list2env` to transfer those changes from the list to individual dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_df <- lst(Apple, Mango, Banana, Potato, Tomato)

list_df <- map(list_df, 
             ~.x %>% rename_with(~'Growth', matches('Growth Level Judgement')))

list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

To run it on single dataframe you can do -

```
Apple %>% rename_with(~'Growth', matches('Growth Level Judgement')))
```

Or in base R -

```
names(Apple)[grep('Growth Level Judgement', names(Apple))] <- 'Growth'
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution.
Perhaps I could not clarify in my post. I want to run one generalised statement separately across all the data frames.
I do not want to list or run it across all the data frames together.

Comment: Did you try running `Apple <- Apple %>% rename_with(~'Growth', matches('Growth Level Judgement')))` ?

Comment: Can multiple changes be made within a single ```rename_with()``` command?

Comment: Do you mean like this ? `mtcars %>% rename_with(~c('A', 'B'), matches('mpg|cyl')) %>% head`

Comment: It did not work in my original data, I get the following error:

```
Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "Overall Indicator Level Judgement" at locations 54, 56, 58, and 60.
  * "10 Learning Community Participation" at locations 55, 57, 59, and 61.
```

Comment: Well without knowing details of your original data I don't think I'll be able to debug this further. In the previous comment I have shown how it works on `mtcars` dataset. If you are unable to resolve this feel free to ask a new question with details of your original data.

Answer (score 2):

Use `endsWith` from `base R`

```
names(Apple)[endsWith(names(Apple), 'Growth Level Judgement')] <- 'Growth'
```

Based on the documentation `?endsWith`, it could be faster

> startsWith() is equivalent to but much faster than

> substring(x, 1, nchar(prefix)) == prefix
> or also

> grepl("^", x)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution could be:

```
Apple %>% 
      rename_with(~'Growth', ends_with('Growth Level Judgement'))
```